# Handling (spawning/removing) entities in SFML

Tags: c++, collision-detection, procedural-generation, sfml

I am unsure which method to use to handle my enemies in SFML.

The idea that I am trying to recreate is to spawn enemies every so many seconds. Initially I wanted to do this using a vector such as std::vector SpriteVector; The advantages of this method would be that in theory it is easy to add and remove my enemies from the vector. Using the push_back and erase method.

However the error with this at the moment is that when I am trying to check whether the sprite or the arrows are hitting an enemy within my vector it will not work.

I know that I could possibly use an array to store the enemies then set their state when hit to false however I am not sure how this will effect spawning my enemies. The functionality of being able to add to a vector is what I think I will need. Otherwise I am sure not sure how to get around the issue of having a certain number of enemies within the array then spawning more over a series of time.

Is this the best way to go about the task I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Why can't you loop through the vector and check collisions?

Comment: When I try to do that I get the following error

19
IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "sf::Rect<T>::intersects [with T=float]" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (sf::Sprite)
            object type is: sf::FloatRect                                           


Error 17 error C2664: 'bool sf::Rect<T>::intersects(const sf::Rect<T> &) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'sf::Sprite' to 'const sf::Rect<T>

Comment: Have you tried "sprite_vector_name[#].getGlobalBounds()" to compare with rather than just "sprite_vector_name[#]"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is an [object pool](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html). You can create such a pool with constant time (O(1) complexity) creation and deletion, which is perfect for your case, I believe.

Let's say you have an Entity class:

```
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity* getNext(void) const { return m_state.next; }
    void setNext(Entity* next) { m_state.next = next; }

private:
    // Entity data...

    // Store either entity data or the next one in the pool.
    union{
        // Entity data.
        struct{
            int x, y;
        } position;

        // Next entity pointer used by object pool.
        Entity* next;
    } m_state;
};
```

You'll need a pool class for managing all entities:

```
class EntityPool
{
public:
    explicit EntityPool(void) :
    m_entities(new Entity[MAX_ENTITIES])
    m_firstAvailable(nullptr) {
        // Assign first available entity.
        m_firstAvailable = m_entities[0];

        // Assign each entity's next pointer.
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ENTITIES - 1; ++i){
            m_entities[i].setNext(&m_entities[i + 1]);
        }

        // Terminate end of array.
        m_entities[MAX_ENTITIES - 1].setNext(nullptr);
    }

    ~EntityPool(void){
        delete[] m_entities;
    }

    Entity* create(void){
        // Check if pool is full.
        assert(m_firstAvailable != nullptr);

        // Pull out the next available entity.
        Entity* e = m_firstAvailable;
        m_firstAvailable = e->getNext();

        // Init entity if needed...
        // ...

        return e;
    }

    void destroy(Entity* e){
        // Reset entity data...
        // ...

        e->setNext(m_firstAvailable);
        m_firstAvailable = e;
    }

private:
    static const int MAX_ENTITIES = 256;
    Entity m_entities[MAX_ENTITIES];
    Entity* m_firstAvailable;
};
```

So then, creating and destroying entities is simple. To create one, use it, and destroy it would look something like this:

```
Entity* monster = m_entityPool.create();
// Do things with monster...
// ...
// Monster is dead, remove it.
m_entityPool.destroy(monster);
```

You can also add an update() function to the pool to iterate through all the entities. This is a very simple example of a pool, and should be expanded upon in your own implementation.

Comment: An object pool is a good idea, but I just want to add that it might be better to take the last object in the pool to fill in a deletion rather than trying to keep count of all the holes made by removed objects. There's also no shame in iterating through a linked list if MAX_ENTITIES is small or the entities don't need to be searched.